# Add Item after NTH element with ion-item

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic4

I would like to add an image after every 8 items. This image would be the only item in the ion-item element. This image is not part of the items array and come from another array.

I'm using this (simplified) code:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index" (click)="goTo()>
    <img src="{item.image}}">
    <h2>{{ item.name }}</h2>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

How could I insert an image every 8 items ?

Comment: It'd be always the same image? Or it comes from another array?

Comment: @sebaferreras another array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the index of the `ngFor` and the modulo operator to achieve that. Please take a look at **[this working StackBlitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/images-array)** (*the demo uses Ionic 3 but the logic is exactly the same for Ionic 4*).

In the following code I just created two list to have some items to show in the view:

**Component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  public items = [];
  public otherImages = [];

  constructor() {

    // Prepare some items
    for(let i = 1; i < 30; i++) {
      this.items.push({
        name: `Item ${i}`,
        image: `https://via.placeholder.com/160x160?text=Item+${i}`
      });
    }

    // Prepare some extra images
    for(let j = 1; j < 5; j++) {
      this.otherImages.push({
        image: `https://via.placeholder.com/160x160?text=Another+Image+${i}`
      });
    }
  }
}
```

**Template**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <h2>Welcome to Ionic!</h2>

  <ion-list>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">

      <ng-container *ngIf="i > 0 && i % 8 === 0; else noImage">

        <!-- First show the image -->
        <ion-item *ngIf="i >= 8 && otherImages[i / 8 - 1]">
          <img [src]="otherImages[i / 8 - 1].image">
        </ion-item>

        <!-- Then show the item -->
        <ion-item>
          <img [src]="item.image">
          <h2>{{ item.name }} </h2>
        </ion-item>

      </ng-container>

      <ng-template #noImage>

        <!-- Only show the item -->
        <ion-item>
          <img [src]="item.image">
          <h2>{{ item.name }}</h2>
        </ion-item>

      </ng-template>

    </ng-container>
  </ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

In the code above, the first `*ngFor="let item of items; let i = index"` just goes through the list of items in the `items` array.

Then we can check the index to see if `i > 0 && i % 8 === 0` which means that the current index is the 8th, 16th, 24th,... element of the array.

Since arrays are zero based, the index 8 means the 9th element. This means that we need to show first the *extra image*, and then the 9th element from the `items` array.

Please notice that in order to get the right image from the `otherImages` array, we need to get the index doing: `otherImages[i / 8 - 1].image`.

```
      <ng-container *ngIf="i > 0 && i % 8 === 0; else noImage">

        <!-- First show the image -->
        <ion-item *ngIf="i >= 8 && otherImages[i / 8 - 1]">
          <img [src]="otherImages[i / 8 - 1].image">
        </ion-item>

        <!-- Then show the item -->
        <ion-item>
          <img [src]="item.image">
          <h2>{{ item.name }} </h2>
        </ion-item>

      </ng-container>
```

If the index is different, we just need to show the item:

```
      <ng-template #noImage>

        <!-- Only show the item -->
        <ion-item>
          <img [src]="item.image">
          <h2>{{ item.name }}</h2>
        </ion-item>

      </ng-template>
```

Comment: Thank you for this well detailed solution!

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped @LucienDubois :)